# Fastest way to concatenate multiple files column wise - Python

Tags: python, shell, text-files, delimiter, paste

**What is the fastest method to concatenate multiple files column wise (within Python)?**

Assume that I have two files with 1,000,000,000 lines and ~200 UTF8 characters per line.

**Method 1:** Cheating with `paste`

I could concatenate the two files under a linux system by using `paste` in shell and I could cheat using `os.system`, i.e.:

```
def concat_files_cheat(file_path, file1, file2, output_path, output):
    file1 = os.path.join(file_path, file1)
    file2 = os.path.join(file_path, file2)
    output = os.path.join(output_path, output)
    if not os.path.exists(output):
        os.system('paste ' + file1 + ' ' + file2 + ' > ' + output)
```

**Method 2:** Using nested context manager with `zip`:

```
def concat_files_zip(file_path, file1, file2, output_path, output):
    with open(output, 'wb') as fout:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as fin1, open(file2, 'rb') as fin2:
            for line1, line2 in zip(fin1, fin2):
                fout.write(line1 + '\t' + line2)
```

**Method 3:** Using `fileinput`

Does `fileinput` iterate through the files in parallel? Or will they iterate through each file sequentially on after the other?

If it is the former, I would assume it would look like this:

```
def concat_files_fileinput(file_path, file1, file2, output_path, output):
    with fileinput.input(files=(file1, file2)) as f:
        for line in f:
            line1, line2 = process(line)
            fout.write(line1 + '\t' + line2)
```

**Method 4**: Treat them like `csv`

```
with open(output, 'wb') as fout:
    with open(file1, 'rb') as fin1, open(file2, 'rb') as fin2:
        writer = csv.writer(w)
        reader1, reader2 = csv.reader(fin1), csv.reader(fin2)
        for line1, line2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
          writer.writerow(line1 + '\t' + line2)
```

Given the data size, which would be the fastest?

Why would one choose one over the other? Would I lose or add information?

For each method how would I choose a different delimiter other than `,` or `\t`?

Are there other ways of achieving the same concatenation column wise? Are they as fast?

Comment: ... did you try to profile? The answer to this question probably depends on the hardware, OS and python version...

Comment: It seems like `fileinput` reads the file sequentially and don't read the files in parallel.

Comment: Method 1 took 2.098e-05 and Method2 took 2.914 ... Is there no comparable equivalence to the `paste` cheat?

Answer (score 5):

From all four methods I'd take the second. But you have to take care of 
small details in the implementation. 
(with a few improvements it takes *0.002 seconds* meanwhile the original implementation takes about *6 seconds*; the file I was working was 1M rows; but there should not be too much difference if the file is 1K times bigger as we are not using almost memory).

Changes from the original implementation:

- Use iterators if possible, otherwise memory consumption will be penalized and you have to handle the whole file at once.
  (mainly if you are using python 2, instead of using zip use itertools.izip)
- When you are concatenating strings, use "%s%s".format() or similar; otherwise you generate one new string instance each time.
- There's no need of writing line by line inside the for. You can use an iterator inside the write.
- Small buffers are very interesting but if we are using iterators the difference is very small, but if we try to fetch all data at once (so, for example, we put f1.readlines(1024*1000), it's much slower).

Example:

```
def concat_iter(file1, file2, output):
    with open(output, 'w', 1024) as fo, \
        open(file1, 'r') as f1, \
        open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        fo.write("".join("{}\t{}".format(l1, l2) 
           for l1, l2 in izip(f1.readlines(1024), 
                              f2.readlines(1024))))
```

Profiler original solution.

We see that the biggest problem is in write and zip (mainly for not using iterators and having to handle/ process all file in memory).

```
~/personal/python-algorithms/files$ python -m cProfile sol_original.py 
10000006 function calls in 5.208 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    5.208    5.208 sol_original.py:1(<module>)
    1    2.422    2.422    5.208    5.208 sol_original.py:1(concat_files_zip)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    **9999999    1.713    0.000    1.713    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}**
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
    1    1.072    1.072    1.072    1.072 {zip}
```

Profiler:

```
~/personal/python-algorithms/files$ python -m cProfile sol1.py 
     3731 function calls in 0.002 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 sol1.py:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 sol1.py:3(concat_iter6)
 1861    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sol1.py:5(<genexpr>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
 1860    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'readlines' of 'file' objects}
    **1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}**
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
```

And in python 3 is even faster, because iterators are built-in and we dont need to import any library.

```
~/personal/python-algorithms/files$ python3.5 -m cProfile sol2.py 
843 function calls (842 primitive calls) in 0.001 seconds
[...]
```

And also it's very nice to see memory consumption and File System accesses that confirms what we have said before:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v python sol1.py
Command being timed: "python sol1.py"
User time (seconds): 0.01
[...]
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 7120
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 914
[...]
File system outputs: 40
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0


$ /usr/bin/time -v python sol_original.py 
Command being timed: "python sol_original.py"
User time (seconds): 5.64
[...]
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1752852
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 427697
[...]
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 327696
```

Comment: You can't pass a genexp or listcomp to `file.write`.

Comment: @NizamMohamed I'm not sure why you said this. The code compiles and works much faster than any other version listed. If you look closer, I didn't pass any genexp/ listcomp ... there's a "".join(...).

Comment: Is there any way to make this solution generic for more than two files? (because of course adding another (couple) `open()` would be needed like this...)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `for` loop with `writelines` by passing a genexp to it and replace `zip` with `izip` from `itertools` in method 2. This may come close to `paste` or surpass it.

```
with open(file1, 'rb') as fin1, open(file2, 'rb') as fin2, open(output, 'wb') as fout:
    fout.writelines(b"{}\t{}".format(*line) for line in izip(fin1, fin2))
```

If you don't want to embed `\t` in the format string, you can use `repeat` from `itertools`;

```
    fout.writelines(b"{}{}{}".format(*line) for line in izip(fin1, repeat(b'\t'), fin2))
```

If the files are of same length, you can do away with `izip`.

```
with open(file1, 'rb') as fin1, open(file2, 'rb') as fin2, open(output, 'wb') as fout:
    fout.writelines(b"{}\t{}".format(line, next(fin2)) for line in fin1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test your function with `timeit`. This [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)
 could be helpful.

Or the same magic function `%%timeit` in Jupyter notebook. You just need to write `%%timeit func(data)` and you will get a response with the assessment of your function. This [paper](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/lesser-known-ways-of-using-notebooks/) could help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Method #1 is the fastest because it uses native (instead of Python) code to concatenate the files. However it is definitively cheating.

If you want to cheat, you may also consider also writing your own C extension for Python - it may be even faster, depending on your coding skills.

I am afraid Method #4 would not be working, since you are concatenating lists with string. I would go with `writer.writerow(line1 + line2)` instead. You may use `delimiter` parameter of both `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` to customise the delimiter (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).